# how to append static image with path given to $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a div in which data is coming from loop $.each is the loop function which get the data returned from database but i am unable to place static image inside it.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $.getJSON("/Post/GetPosts", null, function (data) {
          $(".div1").html("");

         $.each(data, function (i, item) {
         //make html for div2
         var html += "<div class='div2'>";
         html += item.PostedByName;
         html += "<img src='" + item.PostedByAvatar + "'height='100' width='100'/>"
   // i have tried something like this
        html += '<img src="~/assests/images/articles.png">';
        html += "</div>";
        $(".div1").append(html);
     });
   });
});
```

At the third last line, u can see what i have tried.
when i debug it, the image url for which it is looking is:

```
     https://localhost:44305/Home/~/assests/images/articles.png
```

but there is no image in home controller.
This is my server side code---

```
         public JsonResult GetPosts()
                  {
                  var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                       PostedByAvatar = _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(post.PostedBy) 
                  });
        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

i have given proper path. how to resolve it.any idea what should i try

Comment: So what is proper path???

Comment: The `~/` URL prefix has no meaning outside of ASP.NET (server-side). Possibly you could have the server call `ResolveUrl()` on it and add the resulting absolute URL to the `item` structure so the client can consume it.

Comment: @A.Wolff i want to stick that static image and want to show count of articles for that particular user along with that image. Path of the image is-- root directory then images folder then articles.png

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi please can u give any short code so that i can understand and use it

Comment: @duke, I can't because you haven't posted the code of your web service, but what I'm suggesting is very close to what you're already doing with `item.PostedByAvatar`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi okk just two min i am posting server side code too in the question

Comment: @duke, well, you could add another property to your anonymous object, e.g. `PostedByImage = Url.Content("~/assests/images/articles.png")`, then use that in your client-side code in the same way you use `PostedByAvatar`.

Comment: okk now i understand what u were saying, okk no problem it will work definitely it will work thnk u sir @FrédéricHamidi

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant access the SSL Server because the certificate is not trusted.
Try to use http instead of https

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try this：

```
var imgUrl = "~/assests/images/articles.png"; 

...

html += "<img src='" + imgUrl + "'>";
```

like the fourth last line.

Comment: not working still searching for same url as i mentioned above

Comment: @duke answer it ,you give me a trample. e.. ha? this only a train of thought。shit